# Posting data to DjangoRestFramework api from ajax errors with 400 bad request

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created a post api with DjangoRestFramework but sending a post request to the API from ajax errors out with 400 bad request.
here is my ajax code:

```
            var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('screenshot', dataURL);
            fd.append('source', '{{source}}');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                processData: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "/api/save_screenshots/",
                data: fd,
            }).done(function(o) {
                console.log('saved');
                alert('image saved');

            });
```

views.py

```
class SocialShareAPIView(CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = SocialShareCreateSerializer
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

Comment: paste your Django code here

Comment: @Dev I have added the View part as well

Comment: Since the number 1 reason for 400 errors are validation errors, please show your serializer. There could also be a hint in the returned payload if you implement `$ajax.fail()` you could already get a hint.